# syslog flooded with messages "wlp16s0: Failed check-sdata-in-driver check, flags: 0x4"

Tags: wireless, syslog

I've got an old laptop with Lubuntu 18.04 that I use from time to time. I noticed that sometimes it gets unresponsive and fan runs at max speed, and the syslog becomes huge, the only way to stop it is with power button. Today, it happened again - 11 GB syslog file when the laptop was started 2 hours ago) and the syslog was flooded with messages like:

```
Jul 11 11:41:55 hp-laptop kernel: [11441.912249] wlp16s0:  Failed check-sdata-in-driver check, flags: 0x4
Jul 11 11:41:55 hp-laptop kernel: [11441.912305] WARNING: CPU: 1 PID: 28197 at /build/linux-PK0ghA/linux-4.15.0/net/mac80211/driver-ops.h:18 drv_sta_state+0x165/0x410 [mac80211]
Jul 11 11:41:55 hp-laptop kernel: [11441.912306] Modules linked in: btrfs zstd_compress xor raid6_pq ufs qnx4 hfsplus hfs minix ntfs msdos jfs xfs ccm rfcomm acpi_call(OE) msr snd_hrtimer snd_seq snd_seq_devi
ce bnep snd_hda_codec_hdmi snd_hda_codec_analog snd_hda_codec_generic wmi_bmof hp_wmi sparse_keymap coretemp snd_hda_intel joydev input_leds snd_hda_codec kvm irqbypass btusb btrtl btbcm btintel bluetooth ecd
h_generic serio_raw snd_hda_core snd_hwdep i915 pcmcia drm_kms_helper yenta_socket pcmcia_rsrc pcmcia_core lpc_ich drm snd_pcm wmi snd_timer snd tpm_infineon soundcore arc4 i2c_algo_bit iwl3945 iwlegacy fb_sy
s_fops syscopyarea sysfillrect sysimgblt mac80211 hp_accel cfg80211 shpchp lis3lv02d mac_hid input_polldev video ip6t_REJECT nf_reject_ipv6 nf_log_ipv6 xt_hl ip6t_rt nf_conntrack_ipv6 nf_defrag_ipv6 ipt_REJEC
T nf_reject_ipv4
Jul 11 11:41:55 hp-laptop kernel: [11441.912362]  xt_comment nf_log_ipv4 nf_log_common xt_LOG xt_multiport xt_limit xt_tcpudp xt_addrtype binfmt_misc nf_conntrack_ipv4 nf_defrag_ipv4 xt_conntrack ip6table_fil
ter ip6_tables nf_conntrack_netbios_ns nf_conntrack_broadcast nf_nat_ftp nf_nat nf_conntrack_ftp nf_conntrack libcrc32c sch_fq_codel iptable_filter cuse parport_pc ppdev lp parport ip_tables x_tables autofs4 
hid_generic usbhid hid firewire_ohci ahci psmouse libahci firewire_core crc_itu_t tg3 pata_acpi ptp pps_core
Jul 11 11:41:55 hp-laptop kernel: [11441.912391] CPU: 1 PID: 28197 Comm: kworker/1:1 Tainted: G        W  OE    4.15.0-109-generic #110-Ubuntu
Jul 11 11:41:55 hp-laptop kernel: [11441.912393] Hardware name: Hewlett-Packard HP Compaq 6710b (GB893EA#ABB)/30C0, BIOS 68DDU Ver. F.18 07/12/2011
Jul 11 11:41:55 hp-laptop kernel: [11441.912421] Workqueue: events_freezable ieee80211_restart_work [mac80211]
Jul 11 11:41:55 hp-laptop kernel: [11441.912451] RIP: 0010:drv_sta_state+0x165/0x410 [mac80211]
Jul 11 11:41:55 hp-laptop kernel: [11441.912453] RSP: 0018:ffffb942427878a8 EFLAGS: 00010282
Jul 11 11:41:55 hp-laptop kernel: [11441.912457] RAX: 0000000000000000 RBX: ffff9272d4640760 RCX: 0000000000000006
Jul 11 11:41:55 hp-laptop kernel: [11441.912459] RDX: 0000000000000007 RSI: 0000000000000082 RDI: ffff9272ffd16490
Jul 11 11:41:55 hp-laptop kernel: [11441.912461] RBP: ffffb942427878e0 R08: 00000000066f6559 R09: 0000000000000004
Jul 11 11:41:55 hp-laptop kernel: [11441.912463] R10: ffffb94241007b10 R11: 0000000000000001 R12: 0000000000000004
Jul 11 11:41:55 hp-laptop kernel: [11441.912466] R13: 0000000000000003 R14: ffff9272d4640cb8 R15: ffff9272d58fe8c0
Jul 11 11:41:55 hp-laptop kernel: [11441.912468] FS:  0000000000000000(0000) GS:ffff9272ffd00000(0000) knlGS:0000000000000000
Jul 11 11:41:55 hp-laptop kernel: [11441.912471] CS:  0010 DS: 0000 ES: 0000 CR0: 0000000080050033
Jul 11 11:41:55 hp-laptop kernel: [11441.912473] CR2: 00007f1b9c798980 CR3: 000000010bdb0000 CR4: 00000000000006e0
Jul 11 11:41:55 hp-laptop kernel: [11441.912481] Call Trace:
Jul 11 11:41:55 hp-laptop kernel: [11441.912504]  sta_info_move_state+0x284/0x360 [mac80211]
Jul 11 11:41:55 hp-laptop kernel: [11441.912526]  __sta_info_destroy_part2+0x36/0x1a0 [mac80211]
Jul 11 11:41:55 hp-laptop kernel: [11441.912548]  __sta_info_flush+0x139/0x1b0 [mac80211]
Jul 11 11:41:55 hp-laptop kernel: [11441.912575]  ieee80211_set_disassoc+0xb9/0x400 [mac80211]
Jul 11 11:41:55 hp-laptop kernel: [11441.912602]  ieee80211_mgd_deauth+0x287/0x440 [mac80211]
Jul 11 11:41:55 hp-laptop kernel: [11441.912639]  ieee80211_deauth+0x18/0x20 [mac80211]
Jul 11 11:41:55 hp-laptop kernel: [11441.912670]  cfg80211_mlme_deauth+0xaf/0x1c0 [cfg80211]
Jul 11 11:41:55 hp-laptop kernel: [11441.912701]  cfg80211_mlme_down+0x66/0x80 [cfg80211]
Jul 11 11:41:55 hp-laptop kernel: [11441.912731]  cfg80211_disconnect+0x12a/0x1e0 [cfg80211]
Jul 11 11:41:55 hp-laptop kernel: [11441.912756]  __cfg80211_leave+0x13e/0x190 [cfg80211]
Jul 11 11:41:55 hp-laptop kernel: [11441.912782]  cfg80211_leave+0x2b/0x40 [cfg80211]
Jul 11 11:41:55 hp-laptop kernel: [11441.912806]  cfg80211_netdev_notifier_call+0x2dd/0x6a0 [cfg80211]
Jul 11 11:41:55 hp-laptop kernel: [11441.912812]  ? __switch_to_asm+0x41/0x70
Jul 11 11:41:55 hp-laptop kernel: [11441.912815]  ? __switch_to_asm+0x35/0x70
Jul 11 11:41:55 hp-laptop kernel: [11441.912818]  ? inetdev_event+0x46/0x540
Jul 11 11:41:55 hp-laptop kernel: [11441.912821]  ? __switch_to_asm+0x41/0x70
Jul 11 11:41:55 hp-laptop kernel: [11441.912825]  ? skb_dequeue+0x59/0x70
Jul 11 11:41:55 hp-laptop kernel: [11441.912829]  notifier_call_chain+0x4c/0x70
Jul 11 11:41:55 hp-laptop kernel: [11441.912832]  raw_notifier_call_chain+0x16/0x20
Jul 11 11:41:55 hp-laptop kernel: [11441.912835]  call_netdevice_notifiers_info+0x2d/0x60
Jul 11 11:41:55 hp-laptop kernel: [11441.912839]  __dev_close_many+0x63/0x110
Jul 11 11:41:55 hp-laptop kernel: [11441.912842]  dev_close_many+0x8c/0x140
Jul 11 11:41:55 hp-laptop kernel: [11441.912846]  dev_close.part.88+0x4a/0x70
Jul 11 11:41:55 hp-laptop kernel: [11441.912849]  dev_close+0x19/0x20
Jul 11 11:41:55 hp-laptop kernel: [11441.912873]  cfg80211_shutdown_all_interfaces+0x77/0xc0 [cfg80211]
Jul 11 11:41:55 hp-laptop kernel: [11441.912909]  ieee80211_handle_reconfig_failure+0x98/0xb0 [mac80211]
Jul 11 11:41:55 hp-laptop kernel: [11441.912944]  ieee80211_reconfig+0x236/0x11b0 [mac80211]
Jul 11 11:41:55 hp-laptop kernel: [11441.912972]  ieee80211_restart_work+0xbb/0xf0 [mac80211]
Jul 11 11:41:55 hp-laptop kernel: [11441.912977]  process_one_work+0x1de/0x420
Jul 11 11:41:55 hp-laptop kernel: [11441.912980]  worker_thread+0x32/0x410
Jul 11 11:41:55 hp-laptop kernel: [11441.912984]  kthread+0x121/0x140
Jul 11 11:41:55 hp-laptop kernel: [11441.912987]  ? process_one_work+0x420/0x420
Jul 11 11:41:55 hp-laptop kernel: [11441.912989]  ? kthread_create_worker_on_cpu+0x70/0x70
Jul 11 11:41:55 hp-laptop kernel: [11441.912993]  ret_from_fork+0x35/0x40
Jul 11 11:41:55 hp-laptop kernel: [11441.912996] Code: 48 85 c9 75 e3 e9 56 ff ff ff 49 8b 87 f8 03 00 00 49 8d b7 18 04 00 00 48 c7 c7 48 be 5c c0 48 85 c0 48 0f 45 f0 e8 db cf f3 f3 <0f> 0b 41 bd fb ff ff ff e9 28 ff ff ff 41 83 fc 02 0f 85 85 00 
Jul 11 11:41:55 hp-laptop kernel: [11441.913038] ---[ end trace 4f0ad461c1e8ac41 ]---
Jul 11 11:41:55 hp-laptop kernel: [11441.913067] ------------[ cut here ]------------
```

How to prevent this from happening again and again?

Thanks!

Comment: Go to the BIOS and check for a newer BIOS. Yours is from 2011.

Comment: No, there's no newer BIOS. The laptop is really old - from 2008

Comment: Is Secure Boot disabled in the BIOS?

Comment: There is no "Secure Boot" option in the BIOS

Comment: There may be a kernel problem. Can you either boot to a prior kernel and see if the problem is gone, and/or boot to a Ubuntu Live DVD/USB and see if the problem is gone.

Comment: I tried different kernels, but the issue still existed. I tried:
cat /etc/NetworkManager/conf.d/default-wifi-powersave-on.conf
[connection]
wifi.powersave = 2
So far, so good, but I need more time to confirm it works

Comment: What happens when you try a Ubuntu Live DVD/USB?

Comment: I tried with Live USB - syslog was not flooded, but wifi connection was down after suspend, was not able to restore it iven if I restart the networkmanager, I had to restart it to fix it. The same thing happened several times, and I had the same issue when I installed it on the hdd. I could continue with the option mentioned above

Comment: Sounds like `wifi.powersave = 2` solves your problem.

Comment: This comment confirms that a parameter change indeed works as desired. Meanwhile, I had the opportunity to check on my previous machine with Mint 18.3 (also a Thinkpad T61, virtually the same Type number). On this machine, the powersave settng (see comment of heynnema) is 3, while on the Mint20 machine, I had to change it to 2! The wireless hardware on both machines is identical: `Device: pci 0x4230 "PRO/Wireless 4965 AG or AGN [Kedron] Network Connection"` Hence it look like it's an issue with kernel or driver.

Comment: The value 2 works very well for me. Thank you for your support